# Loading data from JSON file for one time

Tags: c#, json, singleton

I have a json file which has some hundereds of rows stored like below..

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "A"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "B"
  }
]
```

I am trying to load this into collection of a class. This data is static and wont change, so I need to load this only once.

I have created a class and loading this in private constructor and loading into collection that I have in the class.

```
    public sealed class JsonLoader : IJsonloader
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<Product> products = new List<Product>();

        private JsonLoader()
        {
            using (var r = new StreamReader("data.json"))
            {
                var json = r.ReadToEnd();
                products = //deserialse the json here 
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Product> Products => this.products;
    }
```

Implement singleton using structure map singleton option. I want to know if my way of implementation is correct or if this can improved any further?

or Any other best way to do it? any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Is it a conscious design decision not to use a library like `Newtonsoft.Json` for the actual serialization? The thing is, even if you only want to read the file once, by calling `ReadToEnd` you will read the complete file contends and create a string from them - you loose the streaming. Using a lib you could avoid that as well as not re-implementing something which other people have already solved well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i done example that taking string of json object Deserialize it and create Product object and add it to Product
 list

```
public class Program
{
    public class Product
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
        string json = "{\"Id\": 1, \"Name\": \"A\"},{\"Id\": 2, \"Name\": \"B\"}";

        string[] jsonArray = json.Split(new string[] { "},{" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (string j in jsonArray)
        {
            string jsonTemp = j.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
            string myJson = "{" + jsonTemp + "}";

            productList.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(myJson));
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**
you will have 2 objects in product list.

I made it in Main for example, you can take it to external function that gets string as parameter and returns list of users (it will be most correct).

Comment: could use a few lines of explanation to go with the code dump

Comment: one sec i will make it full with all the explanations

Comment: don't worry i don't down vote with out giving people a chance to fix an answer, unless the answer is completely off topic and useless which this is definitely not